# Passing Angular Custom Component via HTML from DB

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass an angular component via HTML stored in a database.

Part of our website is a blog, and as part of blog posts we have videos.

I also have this component;

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as Plyr from 'plyr';
import { File } from 'server/misc/schemas/file.schema';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  template: `
    <video  #video
            controls
            crossorigin
            playsinline>
        <source [src]="videoFile.url | cmsUrl" [attr.type]="videoFile.mime" [attr.size]="videoFile.size">
    </video>
  `
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input('video') videoFile: File;
  @ViewChild('video') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const element = this.el.nativeElement;
      new Plyr(element);
    }
  }
}
```

So I want to put `<app-video-player [video]="videoRef"><app-video-player>` in the blog html, but it seems to get sanitised.

Is it sensible to turn off all sanitising if I know the only source will be my DB?

Comment: that is hardly possible. if you try to look through the compiled angular application you will see that there is NO templates in the resulting code. instead you got component factories that are a piece of js code built from your html. so you should try to build another logic to fulfill your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a pipe to allow html insertion

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

transform(html: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<div [innerHTML]="customInsertedHtmlData | safeHtml"></div>
```

This allows you to only turn of html sanitation in objects you trust. Hopefully this can help you towards a solution in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did get this far, and I have the tag displayed in the HTML on the page, it has just not been identified/activated/resolved by Angular.